# Decision tree classifier using scikit learn is having some issues

Tags: python, scikit-learn, spyder

I am trying to implement decision tree classifier using sci kit learn. I have imported it from sklearn but the `.fit()` is showing some issues.

I am writing the code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris from sklearn import tree

iris = load_iris()

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

with open("iris.dot", 'w') as f:

   f = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=f)
import os

os.unlink('iris.dot')
```

Here is the error message:

> File "", line 5, in clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
>
> File "C:\Users\ChirantanGupta\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.0Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 739, in fit X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
>
> File "C:\Users\ChirantanGupta\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.0Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 173, in fit if getattr(y, "dtype", None) != DOUBLE or not y.flags.contiguous:
>
> NameError: name 'DOUBLE' is not defined

I cannot understand this error.How can it be fixed? Can anyone suggest.

Comment: Never say 'cannot' as there's a 'can' in 'cannot'. Only the 'not' needs to be removed :) Looks like there's a problem with your installation as the error's coming from _the very `sklearn` module_. You could try reloading it, restarting Python and re-installing `sklearn`.

Comment: Working fine without error on my system. Please check your installation.